# Simplified OCR with unchanging font

Tags: c#, ocr

I'm working on a project with a need for a simpler and more accurate OCR tool

My Scenario:

- Weekly images all with the same structure
- I have one small area that I need to get a number from
- Another small area that I need to get text with hyphens from
- The font is always the same (this is where I can get more accurate)
- No other option for the images but a flat rasterized image
- The core software is in C# so a CLI language would be preferrable.
- The images are 300 dpi so there is a great base to work from

I would use a normal OCR program, but I know I can get more accurate results, if not perfect results, because it's always the same font.

So, what is a good approach? I don't want to do a ton of work writing this from scratch, but I don't want an over generalized OCR tool that comes pre trained. I want to train it on this one font so it will get very accurate results. I also don't want to do feature extraction of separating out the words and finding the lines for the letters etc.

Comment: I have had decent luck with [MODI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa167607(v=office.11).aspx); it requires the client to have Office installed however YMMV. Another option is [Tessnet2](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/)

Comment: If you're creating the images, why not use a bar code. That's more accurate than any OCR.

Comment: If I was creating the images, I wouldn't need OCR to know what the text says. I'de just save it before I make the image...

Comment: Are those images scanned or digitally born?

Comment: digital which is why reading the letters is very easy with ocr once it's trained

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use OpenCV's machine learning (e.g. using haar cascades), unless the character's position is really perfectly static - in that case a simple comparison could do the trick (find the best match using absolute sum of differences for example).

Is the font fixed? If not, you could use one of the special OCR fonts to get characters that are hard to confuse, even on worse images.

Although, considering you said you'd like to teach it, you might be best off with machine learning.

Comment: The font is fixed. I don't need to only know it's different though, I need to extract the text from these two specific locations. I would prefer something that I can say readText(Rect rect, Font font) if that makes any sense. (extract text within the given rectangle with the given font)

Comment: With the mentioned haar cascades you'd end up with your letters and a position in your image (essentially rectangles containing the samples), so you'd just have to sort them by position and interpret that.

Comment: I'll look into this further, that sounds like what I need. Reading letter by letter after I have the squares containing characters will be easy. I training it would be very quick from there.

Answer (score 0):

I would employ an economical OCR engine such as TOCR from http://www.transym.com. The license fees are very cheap, the OCR is fast and very accurate results especially if you define a fixed rectangle to extract from and there is no background noise.  You should download a trial version to test the results before committing to a purchase.

By the time you set up a custom OCR engine and train it you will have spent considerably more than the small license fee and you may find the results to be more accurate anyway.

If were were able to see a graphic or two of the text you want to OCR then we would be able to give a more accurate answer.

Comment: the images contain sensitive data. Actually the two spots I need to OCR are the sensitive data, so an example isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should look for field level recognition, where you don't perform OCR for the full image, but specify only a number of fields with coordinates. If you're planning a commercial software and seek enterprise accuracy - have a look at [www.ocrsdk.com](http://www.ocrsdk.com/) - it is a cloud based OCR SDK recently launched by ABBYY. It's now in beta so it's completely free to use. It has a nice method suitable for extracting text from a document and [C# sample codes](https://github.com/abbyysdk/ocrsdk.com/tree/master/dotNet).